# Linux: Use parameter as file shortcut

Tags: linux, bash, parameter-passing

**Cheers** everyone :)

I'm trying to make a linux script. This script shall be called with one parameter, a file stored in my home directory. I can't seem to use

```
cat $var1 >> $1
```

So i have this variable $var1 and I want to save it in a file that does exist and its name is given in **$1**

Anyone help me please!

Comment: So you want to create a script that saves things in the file you indicate as a parameter?

Comment: That's correct :) I'm processing some data in my script and when I'm done, I want to concatenate the information in the file give as a parameter

Comment: Good, now it is clear to me : ) I think both @Veger answer and mine can do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`cat` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) shows the contents of a file.

Unless the value of `$var1` is a file that you want to 'copy' to `$1`, it won't work (probably gives a 'file not found' kind of error).

The easiest solution, I can think of, is to [`echo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) the variable:

```
echo "$var1" >> "$1"
```

As stated by @[glglgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296974/glglgl) it is better to put the variable between double quotes. They prevent spaces messing up the command as they split a parameter into multiple parameters

Comment: Well the easiest way in most cases is the best way.. :D I completely blinded out echo, thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: `echo "$var1" >> "$1"` would be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Then you want to create a script that saves things in the file you indicate as a parameter.

```
file_name=$1 #you get the parameter

...do things...

echo "everything you've done" >> $file_name #case want to append
echo "everything you've done"  > $file_name #case want to overwrite
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me fedorqui, I wish I could give you rep for it as well, unfortunately I don't have 15 rep yet -.-

Comment: No prob! Rep is a matter of time, so welcome and see you soon.